# Зацикливание программы, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: python, массивы

Условие задачи таково: задаются 2 массива с одинаковой размерностью. Нужно создать новый массив, элементы которого состоят из произведения максимального элемента обоих массивов на НОД элементов A[i] и B[i].
Насколько я понимаю, программа останавливается на моменте создания нового массива.

```
from random import random
def arrayInit():[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
    size = int(input("Введите размерность массива: "))
    array = [0] * size
    for i in range (len(array)):
        array[i] = int(random()*50 - 25)
    return array

def arrayOutput(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(array[i], end = ' ')
    print()

def maxElement(array1, array2):
    max1 = array1[0]
    max2 = array2[0]
    for i in range(1, len(array1)):
        if array1[i] > max1:
            max1 = array1[i]
        if array2[i] > max2:
            max2 = array2[i]
    if max1 >= max2:
        print("Максимальный элемент обоих массивов %s" % max1)
        return max1
    else:
        print("Максимальный элемент обоих массивов %s" % max2)
        return max2

def nod(first, second):
    while first != second:
        if first > second:
            first -= second
        else:
            second -= first
    return first

def newArray(array1, array2, maximum):
    new = [0] * len(array1)
    for i in range(len(array1)):
        new[i] = maximum * nod(array1[i], array2[i])
    return new

a = arrayInit()
b = arrayInit()
arrayOutput(a)
arrayOutput(b)
max = maxElement(a, b)
c = newArray(a, b, max)
arrayOutput(c)
```

Comment: так что конкретно происходит, она просто останавливается? или вы встречаете какие то ошибки?

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет, в этом вся суть.
Если смотреть в нижнюю часть кода, то происходит вывод текста о найденном максимальном элементе, и после этого программа находится в простое. Работает, но ничего не происходит, но я не могу найти ошибку. Кажется, что все правильно...

Comment: код ложится в цикле, будем думать

Comment: ложится на вызове функции

Comment: @finally но что же там неправильного, что может вызывать зацикливание?

Comment: хороший вопрос.. я думал дело в функции НОД, переписал ее, но все равно никак, я еще покручу, может не заметил чего

Comment: так, я понял в чем проблема, давайте думать как решать - `nod` не умеет работать в **отрицательными** числами(по крайней мере простая ее реализация), так что либо мы убираем возможность рандомить такие числа, либо переписываем НОД

Comment: Точно... А если брать алгоритм Евклида через остаток от деления, тоже не пойдет?

Comment: я его и брал, тоже ложится..

Comment: Ладно, моя цель была понять в чем ошибка... спасибо большое, дальше сам :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как я уже и говорил, функция `nod` теряется, когда в нее поступают **отрицательные** числа, вот два варианта решения проблемы:

```
array[i] = int(random() * 50 + 25)
```

то бишь просто исключить возможность появления отрицательных чисел.

```
a += -1 if a < 0 else 1
b += -1 if b < 0 else 1
```

либо такой вот костыль, который убирает минус у чисел, раз уж они встретились(но они останутся таковыми в самом массиве, так что..)